# How to animate UIBezierPath inside of draw(_:)?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, caanimation

I have a task to draw rectangle in `draw(_:)` method and to animate height of it.

```
var height = 0
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: height)
    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
    UIColor.green.setFill()
    rectanglePath.fill()
}
```

And I'm looking to animate something like this:

```
func animate() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        self.height = 300
    }
}
```

I also can use `CAShapeLayer` and `CABasicAnimation`, but I don't know how to draw it in `draw(_:)` method. Using `draw(_:)` method is required in this task :(

Comment: What do you mean *"Using `draw(_:)` method is required in this task"*? You override `draw(_:)` to update the rectangle when the OS tells you the it needs updating...

Comment: Correct. "Required" means I have to use this method in this task. I know there are others way to solve it, but I have you use method draw(_:)

Comment: Well, that's like saying *"I must evaluate the text entered into a field before the user enters any text."* Just because you think you must do a task in a particular function does not mean that is the correct place to do it. Perhaps if you edit your question and explain exactly what you want to do and why you think it must be done in `draw(_:)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
class View: UIView{
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
{
    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.frame)
    UIColor.green.setFill()
    rectanglePath.fill()
}}
class ViewController: UIViewController{

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let subview = View(frame:  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 0))
    self.view.addSubview(subview)

    UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(
       withDuration: 2,
       delay: 0,
       options: .curveLinear,
       animations: {self.view.subviews[0].frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)}
    )

}}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it doesn't animate path. Frame is not what I can use for animation

Comment: You are welcome. The only UIView properties that can be animated are frame, bounds, center, transform, alpha, backgroundColor: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview